# Sublime Text 3 - Soda Dark Tab Issue

Tags: text, tabs, editor

I recently installed Soda Dark on my installation of Sublime Text 3, and immediately, I noticed there was something wrong with the tabs. As a result, discouraging me to use the theme.

[image: soda dark]

How would I fix this? The tabs are suppose to look like:

[image]

Comment: Does it persist if you quit and re-open Sublime?

Comment: Yeah it did, I just found the error though. I didn't have Node.js installed.

Comment: That shouldn't have been the error, I am using that theme right now on a computer without Node at all. But glad it's working for you..